# Error converting command line cURL into PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to convert command line curl into php curl. It's IBM Speech to Text service. Line was as follow:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary @audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9"
```

I was try this:

```
$url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9";

$postData = array(
    'upload' => '@D:\Others\xampp2\htdocs\test\test.wav',
    'Accept' => "application/json",
);
foreach($postData as $key=>$value){
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "MYUSER:MYPASS");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: audio/wav',
    'continuous: true',
    ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

But I am getting this message:

```
string(129) "{
   "code_description": "Bad Request", 
   "code": 400, 
   "error": "Stream was 69 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes."
}"
```

What may be the problem? Any suggestion will be very helpful.

**Update**

```
$postData = array(
    'upload' => '@D:\Others\xampp2\htdocs\test\test.wav',
    'Accept' => "application/json",
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "MYUSER:MYPASS");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: audio/wav',
    'continuous: true',
    ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Now getting this error:

```
string(139) "{
   "code_description": "Bad Request", 
   "code": 400, 
   "error": "unable to transcode data stream audio/wav -> audio/x-float-array "
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're building your own POST string:

```
$postData = array(
    'upload' => '@D:\Others\xampp2\htdocs\test\test.wav',
    'Accept' => "application/json",
);
foreach($postData as $key=>$value){
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
```

If you provide a string, CURL sends that string out as-is with no further processing. That means CURL won't parse the provided `$fields_string` to see if there's any `@`-prefixed values that indicate a file-upload, and you end up sending the literal text `@D:\etc...` to the server, not the contents of the file you think should be going.

Do not build your own query string/body - just provide the original array to CURL. It'll do the rest:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
                                      ^^^^^^^---your original array
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But Now I am getting this error: string(139) "{
   "code_description": "Bad Request", 
   "code": 400, 
   "error": "unable to transcode data stream audio/wav -> audio/x-float-array "
}"

Comment: any reason your CLI version is using a flac file, and the php version a .wav? .wav is a container, and can contain basically any kind of codec, which watson may not be able to interpret/understand.

Comment: That's like saying they support books. a book's a book, but can be written in any language. if you support english books, then a chinese book is of no use.

Comment: Yes, but I am using suggested codec PCM, sample rate 16000. Still not sure :(